# Can not run nginx webserver in docker

Tags: docker, nginx

Hello i am trying to make a `nginx` server work in container.I have followed this guide :
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Vyp5_F42NGs

When i run the command `docker run --name my-nginx -p 80:80 nginx:1.10.2-alpine` instead of the server starting i get the following error:

```
C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\Resources\bin\docker.exe: Error response from daemon: Conflict. The container name "/my-nginx" is already in use by container "06e1b1fdbfa2aff0a977fb73ce7895fd1deb2986080c83a1af5d292f8f3d2791". You have to remove (or rename) that container to be able to reuse that name.
See 'C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\Resources\bin\docker.exe run --help'.
```

After i execute `docker ps -a` i get a docker instance somehow which anyway does not run.

[image: Nginx is created]

What am i missing here?

Answer (score 0):

Docker is unable to bring up your container using the same name because, the name was taken up by the container that was created the first time you executed this command. I see a couple of solutions to this:

1. [Remove](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/rm/) the container older container first, and try again:

   ```bsh
   $ docker rm my-nginx
   $ docker run --name my-nginx -p 80:80 nginx:1.10.2-alpine
   ```
2. [Start](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/start/) or [restart](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/restart/) the old container:

   ```bsh
   $ docker restart my-nginx
   ```